# creating Subplots from df/ excel-tabelle with 2 header

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Fundamentally, the code runs through; however, it iterates over the categories and only plots the last one (D) in all of the 4 subplots. I'm not sure how to manage the context to store the data appropriately for experiments and categories, and then plot them in their respective subplots.

```
df = pd.read_excel("somedata.xlsx",  header=[0, 1])

experiments = list(range(1, 29))


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 8))
fig.suptitle('Zeitreihenanalyse für Experimente 1-28')


categories = df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique()

for category in categories:
    row, col = divmod(categories.get_loc(category), 2)
    ax = axes[row, col]

    for experiment in experiments:
        
        data = df.iloc[1:327, experiment].values
        sampling_interval = 30  # Minuten
        time = [t * sampling_interval for t in range(len(data))]

        ax.plot(time, data, label=f'Experiment {experiment}')

    ax.set_xlabel('time (Minutes)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Bioluminescence')
    # ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
plt.show()
```

I want to plot the data from experiments 1-28 (it's in the first header). Each category A, N, D, V (2nd header) will have its own subplot(both have no name/titel btw.). The Y-axis should display the data for each experiment as a time series analysis. There are 324 data points with a 'Sampling interval of the recordings in 30 minutes'. I'm grateful for any help, still very new to this stuff.
[thats hor the df looks like, the categories in the 2nd header repeat for each experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R87jO.png)

[So the plots emerge but I can see that this are all the same data from categorie D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgRRj.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of `df`.

Comment: You are looping over categories, but don't seem to reference the categories. You plot the same thing in each loop: `data = df.iloc[1:327, experiment].values`

Comment: I think thats one of my main problems that the connection from the categories to the data/experiments isn't defined. And honestly I don't know how to address this

Comment: If you follow what @mozway said and provide an example `df` (as code, not an image), perhaps someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Are you over complicating it?

Read your data into a 2D array, plot each row in the appropriate subplot. Done.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

categories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
Nexp = 28
Ncat = 4
Npts = 329

# faking some data, ty for the real data
data = np.arange(Nexp*Npts, dtype=float).reshape(Nexp, Npts)

# fig, axes, reshape the axes in a dictionary indexed by category
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,
                         figsize=(10, 6),
                         layout='constrained')
axes = dict(zip(categories, axes.flatten()))

#plot the data
for exp, pts in enumerate(data):
    trial, index = divmod(exp, Ncat)
    category = categories[index]
    ax = axes[category]
    ax.plot(pts, label='Trial no. '+str(trial+1))
for category, ax in axes.items():
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_title('Category '+category)
fig.suptitle('Suptitle')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you got a point there, I did over complicated it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by changing it:

```
data = df.loc[1:327, (experiment, category)].values
```